# Static flow of water in the presence of a loudspeaker

Tags: water, frequency, vision, flow, resonance

The title, I don't know whether it's correct or not, but I came across a video in youtube, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PkgQQqpH2M.

The author of video used the title and hence I used the same.

The video doesn't seems to be fake because of the "noise" in water flow. But what kind of freq. and why it makes the water flow in this pattern?

---

EDIT1: The title might create some confusion with the nature of the flow. The water drops **are not** stagnant. The water is moving/flowing. but the flow is sort of like standing wave pattern. There are nodes and anti-nodes in the flow. drop which seems stationary are nodes. But as such water seems to flow in and out of the nodal region.

Comment: You could also provide "non conformist" explanation of the video and we could try to crack it down.  Why do **you** think water flow follows that path?

Comment: i don't know..probably because of the resonance of the water inside the tube with the bass played on speakers...and some addendum to water, probably making it sort of non Newtonian fluid...

Comment: I don't know about non-Newtonian fluid, but resonance and oscillations outside the tube do not make sense.  In order to have oscillations you must have equilibrium state and the force that pushes particles into equilibrium, and there is no such force.  And of course oscillations eventually create waves, and when you have waves, you have crests that travel in space...

Comment: ya..it might be fake then..youtube is full of them anyways... :D

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56802/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

According to this link http://www.flixxy.com/static-dripping-water-stroboscopic-illusion.htm
It's not only real, but really cool. The amp is being played at the same frequency as the camera's shutter speed, so since the water is a solid stream as it exits the tube, each new drop falls into the same place the last one was when the camera takes another snapshot, because it's all being affected the same way. I haven't tried it yet, but I plan to.

Comment: There is another demonstration of this effect at http://imgur.com/dupSbtr